# Neural network with fixed length string data - how to code and what about unbalanced datasets

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, feature-engineering

I have a dataset of about 990,000 data with two categories. The data is highly unbalanced (about 2% in one of the categories). Every item is a 12 letter length string that can contain 4 letters (say ABCD).

I was suggested to use neural network for this data. How should I code the . strings as input? Using dummy coding like '1A', '1B', '1C', '1D' etc. and give 1 where it is true and 0 for false leading to 4x12=48 features? Or could I use a kind of categorical variable: 12 features with 4 possible values (A=1, B=2, etc.)?

Does neural networks better work with balanced datasets or could I use it with unbalanced data?

Comment: What is the source of the data?  Would you expect structural "similarities" between strings/any other input you could train with word2vec?  Coding words/strings into high dimensional numeric vectors is quite big field and it would be helpful to narrow down your requirements

Comment: stop treating neural nets as a magic black box, and describe how you would solve this problem (as a person).  what are the actual patterns you are  looking for, then one can formalise this into a statistical learning problem. eg does position matter? does aa in first two positions mean same as 'aa' at end etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Neural networks can't deal with categorical data as-is. You need to do one-hot encoding to use such data.

> Using dummy coding like '1A', '1B', '1C', '1D' etc. and give 1 where it is true and 0 for false leading to 4x12=48 features?

Seems like a valid approach.